# Is there a Chemistry Set for every hat/misc in game?

Tags: team-fortress-2

It seems the last update added some interesting stuff, chemistry sets to be specific.

Do these sets that can strangify hats/miscs exist for every iteration of a hat/misc in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - the official wiki lists the 14 possible chemistry set / strangifiers as of the 27 Aug 2013 patch.

- Bonk Boy
- Fancy Dress Uniform
- Sight for Sore Eyes
- Bird-Man of Aberdeen
- Toss-Proof Towel
- Pomson 6000
- Teddy Roosebelt
- Archimedes
- Villain's Veil
- Camera Beard
- All-father
- Merc's Pride Scarf
- Robro 3000
- Summer Shades

Of these, there are 13 misc items and a single weapon, the Pomson.

Source: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Chemistry_Set

More may be added in later patches but so far the trend seems to be that each specific item has a specific strangifier / chemistry set for it, and only a limited set has been released.

Comment: Agreed. I anticipate we'll have many more strange chemistry sets in the future.